# Why different behavior for "TYPE* const" pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, this, undefined-behavior

Below code is dealing with a `TYPE* const` pointer.

```
struct D {
  void Check ()
  {
    D* const p = new D; // 2nd test is "p = 0;"
    cout<<"p = "<<p<<endl;
    (D*&)p = new D;
    cout<<"p = "<<p<<endl; // prints 0, "p = 0;" at declaration
  }
};

int main ()
{
  D o;
  o.Check();
}
```

My questions are,

1. If you initialize with `0`, then even though typecasting next time will not work. Is doing such typecasting is undefined behavior ?
2. `this` pointer is also of `TYPE* const` type, then why compiler doesn't allow the same operation for `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As others have said, this is undefined behaviour since it attempts to modify a `const` object. If you initialise it with zero then the compiler *might* treat it as a compile-time constant, and ignore any attempt to modify it. Or it might do something entirely different.
2. `this` is not an ordinary variable of type `TYPE * const`; it is an rvalue expression of type `TYPE *`. This means that it cannot be used as the target of an assignment expression, or bound to a non-constant reference, at all.

Comment: Some compilers implement `this` as a `TYPE *const`, which is rvalue-y enough for them.

Comment: @SimonRichter Which compilers? (It means they accept `&this`.)

Answer (score 5):

> Is doing such typecasting is undefined behavior ?

Yes.

```
(D*&)p = new D;
```

It invokes undefined behavior, as it tries to change the const pointer.

Recall that `D* const p` declares a variable `p` which is a `const` pointer to non-const `D`.

Comment: I really meant (D*&)p. But as you said, it takes address of p, I doubt that statement. Because it's not (D*)&p! I am taking reference to the pointer p. Also, why it's restricted for `this`, since that is also the same type.

Answer (score 2):

```
D* const p = 0;
```

This declaration says that `p` is a pointer to `D` that is constant, that is it will never, ever change. It is **always** 0.

```
cout<<"p = "<<p<<endl;
```

Here you display the value of p, which you earlier said would **always** be 0. Guess why a 0 is displayed!

Comment: If you don't initialize with `0` (as in real code above), both `cout` will output different memory locations. If you initialize with `0` then both `cout` will output `0` !

Comment: That's just because the compiler cannot tell what the address will be. You are not allowed to try to change it though, as you promised it should be constant. That's undefined behavior, like Nawaz says. Anything can happen!