# C++ internals: Messing with the this-pointer

Tags: c++, this, this-pointer

I have some questions about the internal workings of C++. I know for example that every member function of a class has an implied hidden parameter, which is the this-pointer (much in the same way Python does):

```
class Foo 
{
    Foo(const Foo& other);
};

// ... is actually...

class Foo
{
    Foo(Foo* this, const Foo& other);
};
```

Is it wrong of me to then assume then that the validity of the function does not directly depend on the validity of this (since it's just another parameter)? I mean, sure, if you try to access a member of the this-pointer, it better be valid, but the function will otherwise continue if this is deleted, right?

For example, what if I were to mess up with the this pointer and do something like what you see below? Is this undefined behavior, or is it defined by highly discouraged? (I'm asking out of pure curiosity.)

```
Foo:Foo(const Foo& other)
{
    delete this;
    this = &other;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign to `this` - it is of type `Foo * const`. You *can* `delete this;` in certain circumstances, but it's rarely a good idea.

Comment: What if I cast away the const-ness?

Comment: I'm sure it's not specifically defined in the standard, but is its definition not implied? Casting away const-ness is defined, from a pure technical standpoint `this` is just another parameter, deleting and assigning pointers is obviously defined... What is there that's not defined?

Comment: @Paul: See 7.1.5.1/4 - In short, attempts to modify something that really is const produces UB

Comment: @Paul: Additionally, see 3.10 on lvalue/rvalue. `this` isn't a lvalue.

Comment: Several misunderstandings: the type of `this` is `Foo*`; no const.  But this isn't a variable; it's a keyword, which represents an rvalue (which is why no const), like `42`.  You can't assign to `this` or modify it, anymore than you could assign to or modify `42`.  And `delete this` is a frequent idiom; in some applications, it's pretty much the only use of `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is defined as,

```
Foo(Foo* const this, ...);
```

Casting away the `const`ness is not **not possible** for `this` (special case). Compiler will give errors for the same. I have asked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659157/why-different-behavior-for-type-const-pointers).