# C++ Classes - What is wrong with my program?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, this

Insert is a method which appends an item to the end of my linked list.

Can't figure out how to code for the case where Node is null, and I just want to add to it.

```
struct Node{
       int data;
       Node *next;

       Node(int data):data(data),next(NULL){}

       void insert(int data){
            if (this==NULL){
               this=new Node(data); // compiler is complaining here.
                                    // how would I go about setting the value of this (which is presently NULL) to a new Node?
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: If `this` is `NULL`, how are you using a member of it? How can `this` be `NULL` in the first place?

Comment: what would the following be?

Node *n = NULL;

Comment: That's a pointer to a `Node`. No `Node` is created from that. The `NULL` there simply signifies that it isn't pointing to anything.

Comment: @user1202422: You cannot call a member on a null pointer. `this` in `insert` is a `Node const *` (i.e. cannot be changed)... You need to revisit your design, consider that you want to `append` a new `Node` to a *list*... maybe you are missing the list?

Comment: so if i did:
n = new Node;
n.insert(5); // at this step, wouldn't the insert be running on an empty node?

Comment: @user1202422: In that case, `next` will be `NULL` not `this`. So you need to do `next = new Node(data)`.

Comment: @user1202422, the insert would be running on a node you just created with new. Actually it wouldn't run at all because you used a dot instead of an arrow.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659157/why-different-behavior-for-type-const-pointers).

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning you'll get a memory leak unless you `delete` whatever you `new` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not assign a value to ***this*** pointer which is a special keyword and should always point to a valid block of memory. by looking at your usage, could you be trying to mean this:

```
void insert(int data){
            if (!next){
               next = new Node(data);

            }
```

Comment: to above, what if i had:

int main(){
     Node *n = new node;
     n->insert(5); // in this case, we'd want the method to do the equivalent of: n->data = data, n->next = NULL.
}

Comment: maybe your class should have 2 functions namely setData and insert. n->setData() sets the data of the n, but n->insert() sets the data of the last node in the list. besides, you must have a root node with a data to actually insert something into.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
void insert(int data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node(data);

    if (next!=NULL)
        newNode->next = next;
    next = newNode;
}
```

You cannot assign directly to 'this'; what you need to consider is how to represent an empty list, most likely by:

```
Node* head = 0;
```

So you add the first node by

```
head = new Node(data);
```